# Certain animations not recording

Tags: keyframes

I'm banging my head up against the proverbial brick wall here. I'm doing an animation which is a spoof on a 1960s kids show from UK called Camberwick Green, this starts with a six sided box which rotates for a short time, and then the top slides open to make way for one of the shows characters to slide up through the top. The first pic is of the first frame which is how the box is first shown with the top closed.[image]

The second pic shows, in my own description, how the top opens. the white dots being the pivot points for each individual triangle and the purple arrows which i hope will convey to you the direction/rotation of the triangles so it should open up iris fashion.[image]

The third pic shows the end result of the top sliding open.[image]

Which result I'm pleased with as far as it goes, but the issue arises when i scrub back to the first frame, it shows the box as in the third pic with the lids open rather than closed like it should. when i play the animation, the main box rotates as expected but with the lids totally open all the way through, thereby missing the opening altogether. Here are some details of how i animated: I first inserted a keyframe on frame one, then rotated the whole box -18 degrees at 12 frame intervals for my keyframes. When i hit keyframe 240, i started rotating the triangles -10 degrees on their pivot points as well as the regular rotation of the box as previously stated, so for example at frame 252, i would rotate the box at -18 and this would automatically keyframe at that point, then staying at that frame, i would individually rotate the triangles, with the thinking that I would be keeping the movements on the frame, but the result is a constantly open lid throughout. I've tried manually inserting keyframes with location/rotation/scale etc but the result has always been the same. I would have thought that once a keyframe is recorded, that would be how it should be. Sorry if this is long winded, I've only been learning this for about 4 months. Here is a link to the opening of the show if it's allowed... Many thanks in advance. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DWNR-08Ff0w

Comment: There is a little dot icon on the top of the animation panel. Is it ON ? Because this overwrites your keyframes when you move your object. You may have overwritten the first keyframe of your final when you tweaked the objects to be at the final position

Comment: do you mean the one next to the play/skip/rewind buttons? if so then yes, i do put it on because this automatically records the keyframes, if i do it with it off, for some reason i get no animation at all. Thank you however for replying, i will have a look at that when i get back home from work.

Comment: Well if you want that behaviour, you should FIRST go the desired frame, THEN apply your movement to the object. You should also know that if you move your objects while the animation is playing and the "record" button is on, it will create unwanted keyframes on each frame. An alternative is to not use the record button and right click on the transform value on the "N" panel on the right and "add keyframe" or shortcut "I" when hovering over a transform value

Comment: Thank You friend, it's all food for thought, I'll take on board what you've said, and try a few things out later, luckily at the moment it's only a short one and these issues have arisen before i did too much, it's all an experience.

Comment: Sure thing ! I would say, in my experience, unless you want to record an object over multiple keyframes, you should'nt use the record button but use the "i" shortcut that way you do not risk accidentally overwriting your painfully created object positions. But to each their own !

Comment: Nathan, Hi, just like to tell you I've managed to resolve the issue. My problem was that I was going into edit mode to set up the pivot points on the top pieces for movement, when in fact that is all i should have been doing in edit mode, instead of taking it back to object mode to perform the action, i doing so in edit mode which resulted in the disappointment. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Oh, alright that makes sense ! Consider adding this as an answer to your own question so that someone might find it useful if they encounter the same problem. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

It seems i made a rookie error with this, everything else i was animating in object mode, and i was going into edit mode to set up my pivot points to rotate my top pieces and rotating them there, instead of going back to object mode to move them. This resulted in the pieces being in the fully open position from frame 1 to finish instead of opening during the animation. So if anybody stumbles on this question with the same problem, then note...ALWAYS animate in object mode.